# \pdfmdfivesum error triggered by \begin{thebibliography}

Tags: bibliographies, movie15

I have a class file with over 4000 lines, grown over the years, loading over 60 packages, that worked with TeX Live 2010 without any problem. Now I switched to TeX Live 2014, and I have a one main issue left. The line in the TeX file `\begin{thebibliography}{999}` triggers a `\pdfmdfivesum` error:

```
! Use of \pdfmdfivesum doesn't match its definition.

\pdf@filemdfivesum {->\pdfmdfivesum file{

l.6121 \begin{thebibliography}

                              {999}

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.

\ReFiCh@Check ...#1\edef #2{\ReFiCh@CheckSum {#3}}

                                                  \ifx #2\ReFiCh@Separator #...

l.6121 \begin{thebibliography}

                              {999}
```

Yes, I do use `movie15`, and `hyperref`, and many other packages (over 50).

Yes, I searched through Stack Exchange.

No, using `\usepackage{rerunfilecheck}` before `movie15` does not help.

Can anybody help?

P.S. I use texlive 2014 on OSX, pdflatex with the dvi to ps to pdf route, with \pdfoutput=0, and the package etex.

Comment: Which TeX engine (pdfTeX, LuaTeX, XeTeX) in which version is used?

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: I can't say whether this is connected, but `movie15` is regarded as `obsolete` and superseded by `media9`, see http://www.ctan.org/pkg/movie15

Comment: Is there any news here?